# Export MultiPolygon from MultiSurface layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I have a layer in QGIS that is a Multisurface layer currently stored on a PostGIS server I want to add this layer as a MultiPolygon layer to PostGIS using QGIS.

Can I specify this somehow when I save/export to QGIS? The only workaround I found is exporting the layer to a shape file loading it and exporting it then to PostGIS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- within PostGIS:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE <multipolygon_layer> AS
    SELECT <id>,
           ...,
           ST_CurveToLine(<geom>) AS <geom>
    FROM   <multisurface_layer>
  ;
  ```
- using `ogr2ogr` (*GDAL* > 3.0.5):

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL <pg_conn> -nln <multipolygon_layer_name> -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI <source>
  ```

  or, if the approximated linear geometries will always be areal, simply

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL <pg_conn> -nln <multipolygon_layer_name> -nlt MULTIPOLYGON <source>
  ```

Comment: thanks for the postgis solution. However for ogr it should be from multisurface to multipolygon In fact I've found the solution for the ogr2ogr by myself (simply -nlt MULTIPOLYGON ). Please update your answer.

Comment: @radouxju I added the extra `-nlt` flag, which has the same effect, and a note about using the `MULTIPOLYGON` option. I consider using the appropriate flags as the 'more correct' answer, as these will handle all *SQL-MM* curve types, while using the `MULTIPOLYGON` option fails for when a non-linear type can only be approximated as a *LineString*. If that could ever be the case, or if you really want to have a mixed type relation, is another question.

Comment: thanks for completing the answer.